# Are there any behavior patterns that one can deduce from how a funds chart looks like?

Tags: investing, trading, stock-markets, mutual-funds, chart

The following chart tracks a mutual fund on the last 6 months (maybe someone with a higher reputation can inline the picture for me):

[image: chart]

The big dip in the middle is because of the COVID-19 pandemic. Then, after the bad news hit, the market started to recover.

However, the way the chart looks, it seems that the behavior now is different than the behavior before the pandemic. The red section shows small changes up or down, while the green shows much larger ups and downs. Is there an explanation for this behavior? Is this a sign for panic, confidence, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In times of market uncertainty and in bear markets, day to day price swings are larger and intraday volatility elevated.

This volatility is often more pronounced at market openings and there are more frequent large intraday price swings.  That is what you have been seeing for the past two months.